# Adding hover effect when a keyboard is press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do u add a hover like effect to a div when a specific key on the keyboard is press using jquery ?

```
  <div id="d-up" class="button"></div>
```

Thank you

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: you can add class with hover style on keydown and remove that class on keyup event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like following:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).keypress(function(e){
       $(".button").css("background-color","#ccc");
    });
  
  $(window).keyup(function(e){
       $(".button").css("background-color","#fff");
    });
});
```

```css
.button{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d-up" class="button"></div>
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xk5kqxy/)

On Key press it will add `background-color` of div. (**Press any key to view background-color**) 
Hope it helps.